# PostScript questions on Macs with either Preview or Macghostview

Tags: macos, preview, postscript

1)  The PC implementation of Ghostview has a "Safer" option, checked by default, that prevents file creation (so that running a .ps file can't hurt anything in the environment).  One must uncheck "Safer" to run PostScript files that create files or one gets an invalidfileaccess error.

What is the equivalent of unchecking "Safer" in either or both of the OSX PostScript viewers mention in the title?

2)  If a PostScript program contains an error, where to Preview put (hide?!?!) the error message?

Answer (score 3):

I just started using `MacGhostView` and I have hand-generated `.ps` files that run other `.ps` files using the `run` command. I get `Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run--` in a message window. By default the `SAFER` option for ghostscript is usually enabled in all versions of GhostView, which this app is based on. It is a security precaution that prevents a script from reading/writing from/to a file. I tried adding the `-dNOSAFER` option, which is what you would use with ghostscript, to `Preferences->gv parameters` but it didn't work. Looking through all the menu items, I finally found `Options->Show gv parameters` which displayed the options for this app. The `-dNOSAFER` option is replaced by `-nosafer` in this app. I don't know why they would change any of the options from the original syntax but all of them are like this. I added this option to `Preferences->gv parameters` and now I can open all my files. I also added `-media=LETTER` and `-resize` (separated by spaces) so by default I get a letter-size canvas within a fit window.

I can't open my `.ps` files that violate the `SAFER` option in `Preview` because there is no way to change the options in the app. The ones that do not violate this option seem to be converted to `pdf` before being displayed. I much prefer `MacGhostView`.